# How to generate R.java after importing library project in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have imported a library project from Eclipse to Android Studio. The library project had some resources and hence R.java file. I have not imported R.java from Eclipse. I thought it will be generated automatically by android studio. Now wherever in my code R.something is written I am getting error. So should I copy the same R.java from Eclipse to Android Studio? If no, then how to generate R.java in a library project in Android Studio?

Comment: R.class/java is generated automatically. You can mark your project as Library Module in Android Studio. When you build the project, the R class will be created.

Answer (score 2):

R.java file will automatically generated. Check if any errors in the xml files. If Errors in xml file then the R.java file will not be generated. And try Cleaning the project.

Comment: in my case I had recently added a new layout. Didn't know what was wrong with it (apparently nothing), Then I deleted it, rebuilt and R was generated.

Answer (score 0):

R.java is auto generated every time when you compile(ie when you BUILD) the project. You should not copy the R.java file. Now in Android Studio try to build the lib project